# Create soft round circles HTML5

Tags: html, geometry, rounding

I created circles using HTML5 Canvas.  I want them to look like the soft, round brushes done with Photoshop. In this code, I can only create the circles with specific opacity:

```
 function drawClusters(ctx) {

var startPoint = (Math.PI/180)*0;
var endPoint = (Math.PI/180)*360;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(30,30,10,startPoint,endPoint,true); // x, y, r
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,204)";
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;

ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
}
```

How is it possible to achieve the soft round effect? Something like the following image:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean have some arcs with less or more opacity than others? You can multiply the RGB components by a number between 0 and 1 (i.e., 50% = 0.5)

Comment: No, the same arc to have near the edge, gradually less opacity in contrast with its centre.

Comment: you can also create a little image which you can use brush. Than instead of `ctx.arc`use `ctx.drawImage(<img>, cos(x), sin(y))` on tiny steps…

Comment: based on edit: I guess you should use radial gradients…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pr9r7/2/ - v2, fixed overlaping issue.

```
function my_circle(ctx, x, y, size, color1, color2){
    var color1_rgb = hex2rgb(color1);
    var color2_rgb = hex2rgb(color2);
    var radgrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(
        x, y, size*0,
        x, y, size);
    radgrad.addColorStop(0, "rgba("+color1_rgb.r+", "+color1_rgb.g+", "+color1_rgb.b+", 1)");
    radgrad.addColorStop(1, "rgba("+color2_rgb.r+", "+color2_rgb.g+", "+color2_rgb.b+", 0)");
    ctx.fillStyle = radgrad;
    ctx.fillRect(x-size,y-size,size*2,size*2);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the answer (because it does not use canvas, but plain HTML and CSS), however your question made me play a little :)

http://jsfiddle.net/n5axu/

A DIV can be styled with the [`box-shadow` css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) to get similar circles.

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="circle white"></div>
```

CSS

```
.circle {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 70px 60px;
  position: fixed;
}
.circle.white  { color: white; }
body { background-color: black; }
```

Comment: Yea i have to do it in html5 canvas!